# How do I create this plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the plot I have created in base R:

[image]

I want to create a similar plot shown above in ggplot2 however I can't get the Y axis in ggplot2 to look like the one in base R.

The dataset I am using is the Quacquarelli Symonds Top 100 World University Rankings of 2024 and I am investigating the extent of the relationship between the ranking of a university and its academic reputation. The ranking of a university is numeric and discrete, and is the dependent variable. Academic reputation is numeric and continuous.

This is what I have tried:

```
f <- ggplot(ranking_data, aes(x = academic_reputation, y = rank))
f + geom_point()
```

This is the plot I have created using the library 'ggplot2'.

[image]

I would also like to reverse the scale of the Y axis so that it is going from 100 to 0 upwards.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can use `scale_y_continuous()` to customize the axis ticks. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html

Comment: It looks like your `rank` variable is stored as a factor or character data, since it is being ordered "alphabetically" instead of numerically. In R terms, you don't want a discrete variable type if you want to arrange it on a scale and only label some breaks. Try `ranking_data$rank = as.numeric(as.character(ranking_data$rank))` and then plot again.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jon Spring noted on his comments, your `rank` variable isn't numeric.  A clear indication of this is that some of the labels on the bottom of the axis appear to be something like "= 100".  The fact that a simple `plot()` worked tells us it is stored as a `factor` (if it were a simple `character` vector, `plot()` would have failed). This has two implications:

- Your first plot is **wrong**, since R is plotting the rank of each observation's value on the factor's levels (which are on alphabetical order by default).  So on your plot, the point for the observation with `rank` "=100" (the first, in alphabetical order) will be plotted at y=1, `rank` "=17" at y=2, etc.
- The presence of "=" in your variable means that you can't simply do `as.numeric(as.character(...)` because R won't know how to convert "=100" to `numeric` and will introduce an `NA` (it warns you about this).

My suggestion is to strip the equal signs from the variable using `sub` and only then convert it to `numeric`.  Something like:

```
ranking_data$rank <- sub("=", "", ranking_data$rank)
ranking_data$rank <- as.numeric(ranking_data$rank)
```

You can of course do it in a single step (`as.numeric(sub(...))`, I've separated it for clarity.

P.S: this is a good example of why great care is needed to make sure variables we expect to be `numeric` don't end up as `factor`s, and one of the arguments against the `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` option (which was the default up to some time ago, I think). Something as simple as `plot(1:3, factor(c("1", "10", "100")))` illustrates this clearly.